# Fix grub on UEFI system

Tags: ubuntu, grub, uefi

I have windows 10 installed and am seeking to dual boot with Ubuntu Studio.
Alright so I was installing Ubuntu Studio on an Asus F555L type laptop. At the end of the installation it said "grub failed to install". I tried again and it did it again. So, I then grabbed a boot recovery iso that a friend recommended to me (can post link to that upon request) and attempted to boot of that to reinstall grub. The only problem is that I cannot figure out how to enable Legacy Bios support in the UEFI menu, in fact I don't think it's possible.
So, my question is, does anyone know of how to boot of a live USB that doesn't support UEFI from UEFI firmware, or of any other method of installing grub without reinstalling an OS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you can actually boot from the Live CD. Ubuntu has more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI), but in short, after voting from the live CD:

1. If you don't have a /boot/efi partition, create it
2. Start Boot-Repair, click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab, and select the UEFI partition. Click Apply.

Comment: Okay thank you. I left out that I have windows 10 dual booted and wish to keep that, but that shouldn't change anything. I'll try that.

Comment: Edit your question and add it. That way someone else might give you a better solution.